# MySQL: `Where` clause to get all the records between certain alphabets

Tags: mysql

I have a `table` named countries. It has names of all the countries.

I want to write a query in `MySQL` which will give me all the countries that starts with (let say) letter "C" till letter "G".

So all the countries that starts with letter "C" till letter "G" should be fetched.

Thanks.

Comment: @B001ᛦ I was thinking of using something like `select * from countries where name like 'c%' and name like 'G%'` but this will give me only those countries which starts with "C" and "G"

Comment: i found the duplicate by jus googling your title for no more than 3 seconds (first result). This question shows no effort at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will do the trick

```
SELECT *  FROM countries WHERE LEFT(name, 1) between 'C' and 'G'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex like below

WHERE countryName REGEXP '^[C-G]'